# C# Enum Indexing Question

Tags: c#, enums, indexing

Is it possible to use an index integer to obtain an `enum` value? For example, if...

```
public enum Days { Mon, Tues, Wed, ..., Sun};
```

...is it somehow possible to write something like...

```
Days currentDay = Days[index];
```

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, .net has the `DayOfWeek` enumeration in the `System` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can cast an `int` to an `enum`, if the value you are using is defined in the `enum`, however you do this at your own risk:

```
Days currentDay = (Days)index;
```

If you really want to be safe, you can check if it's defined first, but that will involve some boxing, etc and will damper performance.

```
// checks to see if a const exists with the given value.
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Days), index))
{
    currentDay = (Days)index;
}
```

If you know your enum is a specified, contiguous value range (i.e. Mon = 0 thru Sun = 6) you can compare:

```
if (index >= (int)Days.Mon && index <= (int)Days.Sun)
{
    currentDay = (Days) index;
}
```

You can also use the array passed back by `Enum.GetValues()`, but once again this is heavier than the cast:

```
Day = (Day)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Day))[index];
```

Comment: Thanks James. Option #3 it is! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you index your enums properly, you can just case the int (or whatever index is) to the enum.

So...

```
public enum Days { Mon = 0, Tue, Wed .... }

Days today = (Days)1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some calculations with the `DaysOfWeek` enum before.  I used an extension method to create a safe default.

Here's an example:

```
public enum Days { Invalid = ~0, Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun };
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int day = 8;
        Days day8 = (Days)day;
        Console.WriteLine("The eighth day is {0}", day8);

        Console.WriteLine("Days contains {0}: {1}", 
            day, Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Days), day));

        Console.WriteLine("Invalid day if {0} doesn't exist: {1}", 
            day, day8.OrDefault(Days.Invalid) );

        Console.WriteLine("Sunday day if {0} doesn't exist: {1}", 
            day, day8.OrDefault(Days.Sun));

        Days day9 = ((Days)9).OrDefault(Days.Wed);
        Console.WriteLine("Day (9) defaulted: {1}", 9, day9);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public static class DaysExtensions
{
    public static Days OrDefault(this Days d, Days defaultDay) 
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Days), (Days)d))
        {
            return d;
        }

        return defaultDay;
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
The eighth day is 8
Days contains 8: False
Invalid day if 8 doesn't exist: Invalid
Sunday day if 8 doesn't exist: Sun
Day (9) defaulted: Wed
```

Comment: Please don't mark this as the accepted answer. I just wanted to share an alternative solution that others may find helpful.